# How to find the files in magento directory

Tags: magento-1.7, vat, tax-class

I want to get the list of taxes to display on cart page..
The code that is using to display the tax is :

This block is showing tax information:

```
$this->renderTotals();
```

while this block is shwoing grand total:

```
<?php echo $this->renderTotals('footer'); ?>
```

But i need to made some changes... please tell me which file i have to look for so i can make the changes...

I tried all the files adn check the coding.. but no success...
Please help me....

Comment: turn on the [template path hints](http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-turning-on-template-path-hints/)

Comment: use magento developer toolbar extension to easy to idea which function, controller and how to access this with file path.

Answer (score 1):

The class for this block is defined in the file Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Totals.php
If you open this file you will find renderTotals() defined here. I think you are interested in making changes here. If yes, you can override this class and make your changes.

Answer (score -1):

Check this file out:

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/total/tax.phtml